# Add MatDialog popup to Angular Root and not to body

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have made an Angular 6 app where I have some MatDialog. This works perfectly in development mode.

Now I have to implement this into an existing website (that uses sitecore 9).
This works great, except that the dialogs won't open correctly.
I've found out that the dialogs are added to the body and not to my angular root DOM element.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <app-library>...</app-library>

    <div class="cdk-overlay-container">...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to add the dialog to the angular app element (in my case ) and not to the body element?

I've already tried to use the viewContainerRef option matDialog, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(..., public viewRef: ViewContainerRef) {
}

export class FilterToggleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(..., public dialog: MatDialog, private appRef: ApplicationRef) {}
  openFilterPanel() {
    const viewRef = (this.appRef.components[0].instance as AppComponent).viewRef;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FilterPanelComponent, {
      width: '100vw',
      height: '100%',
      panelClass: 'search-filter-panel-modal',
      viewContainerRef: viewRef
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you have any control over the overlay container. Please explain "won't open correctly" - that might be fixable.

Comment: There's a scroll animation to the bottom of my page and it adds whitespace inside my html. 

I could fix it by making my MatDialog position fixed, but that's not the result I want (I want the dialog to be restricted to my angular app DOM element).

If it's not possible, i'll have to make it position fixed I guess...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Angular Material [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig), `viewContainerRef` option of `MatDialogConfig` is:

> Where the attached component should live in Angular's logical component tree. This affects what is available for injection and the change detection order for the component instantiated inside of the dialog.
>
> #### This does not affect where the dialog content will be rendered.

When inspecting the DOM when a dialog is opened, we'll find the following component hierarchy:

1. **`Body`** - `<body>`
2. **`OverlayContainer`** - `<div class="cdk-overlay-container"></div>`
3. **`Overlay`** - `<div id="cdk-overlay-{id}" class="cdk-overlay-pane">`
4. **`ComponentPortal`** - `<mat-dialog-container></mat-dialog-container>`
5. **`Component`** - our `ComponentExampleDialog` component, which is opened like: `this.dialog.open(ComponentExampleDialog)`.

Now, what we really need to change is the position in the DOM of the `OverlayContainer`, which, according to [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#the-overlay-container), is:

> the container element in which all individual overlay elements are
>   rendered.
>
> #### By default, the overlay container is appended directly to the document body.

Technically, it is possible to provide a **custom** overlay container, as described in [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#the-overlay-container), but, unfortunately, it is a **singleton** and creates a potential problem:

`MatDialog`, `MatSnackbar`, `MatTooltip`, `MatBottomSheet` and all components that use the `OverlayContainer` will open within this custom container.

If this is not a problem, use the following code, which attaches the overlay container to the element with `id="angular-app-root"`:

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: AppOverlayContainer}],
 // ...
})
export class MyModule { }

export class AppOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {

  protected _createContainer(): void {
    const container: HTMLDivElement = document.createElement('div');
    container.classList.add('app-overlay-container');

    const element: Element | null = document.querySelector('#angular-app-root');
    if (element !== null) {
      element.appendChild(container);
      this._containerElement = container;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, add the following css:

```
.app-overlay-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.app-overlay-container:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wksbmf

Also the following article might be useful, because it contains a similar implementation:
https://blog.bbogdanov.net/post/angular-material-overlay-hack-overlay-container/

Comment: I found I needed `position: fixed`, not `position: absolute`.

Comment: Also, if you need to do this in an Angular Elements web component, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67512186/11991371

Answer (score 0):

@andreivictor's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61074576/5190118) worked for me (with `position: fixed`), and made sure my backdrop and spinner only cover the Angular Elements web component.

I also have a `mat-drawer` in my app.  Originally I was appending `app-overlay-container` to the component that was contained in `mat-drawer-content`.  The `mat-drawer`, when it opens, contains a form that contains a select (drop-down) element.  Whilst everything else worked, the select was no longer visible and hence was unusable.  I discovered that `mat-select-panel` elements were appearing in the `app-overlay-container`, which was covered up by the very `mat-drawer` that had spawned the `mat-select-panel`.

The lesson learned is that `app-overlay-container` really must be added to the outermost element in an Angular Elements web component.  I ended up adding an extra wrapper/container `div` in `app.component.html` purely to achieve this, which I was reluctant to do, but was the only way I could get it to work.  The wrapper `div` needed to have `width` and `height` specified explicitly, and the element that was previously outermost needed both `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`.  (But YMMV as some of these may be specific to my individual project.)